# Call multiple dependant Http calls in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi have four HTTP calls in my application (after a button click) in which the forth call is dependent on the above three calls.
I want the forth call to wait and get data from all three. (the data which I get from the three calls needs to by sent as input to the forth call)

```
LoadDetails() {
    this.DataService.M1().subscribe((Model1: Project.Models.Model1[]) => {
        this.SomeData1 = Model1;
    });
    this.DataService.M2().subscribe((Model2: Project.Models.Model2[]) => {
        this.SomeData2 = Model2;
    });
    this.DataService.M3().subscribe((Model3: Project.Models.Model3[]) => {
        this.SomeData3 = Model3;
    });
    this.DataService.M4(this.SomeData1.Id, this.SomeData2.Id, this.SomeData3.Id).subscribe((Model4: Project.Models.Model4[]) => {
        this.SomeData4 = Model4;
    });
}
```

How do I make the forth call wait for above three calls to complete?

Comment: For the next time: Please format your code, it looks unprofessional if you paste code like this.

Comment: Will surely take care

Comment: This is already covered in SO Documentation http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/27973/sending-multiple-parallel-http-requests#t=201702271308241102435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
LoadDetails() {
    Observable.forkJoin([this.DataService.M1(), this.DataService.M2(), this.DataService.M3()]).mergeMap((datas:any[]) => {
        this.SomeData1 = data[0];
        this.SomeData2 = data[1];
        this.SomeData3 = data[2];

        //Here you can do whatever you want, bevor you request SomeData4
        return this.DataService.M4(this.SomeData1.Id, this.SomeData2.Id, this.SomeData3.Id);
    }).subscribe((Model4: Project.Models.Model4[]) => {
        this.SomeData4 = Model4;
    });
}
```

This requests `SomeData1-3` simultaneously and if all data is present, it will request `SomeDate4`;

Note:

If you do not load all RxJS operators, you have to add following imports:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

Comment: I need to do some calculations after calling the 3 http calls then give those result as input to forth call.

Comment: @Arun you can do this inside the mergeMap callback. I will mark the line for you.

Comment: I am new to angular2. Can you provide me any link or any source code how to do that. To be more clear, I call the services 1,2 and 3. Get the data. Do some calculations and then call the 4th service with the calculated data

Comment: @Arun I wrote the code for you. Can you tell me what's not clear? Just copy past it and add your calculations where I wrote my comment.

Comment: To the downvoter: Please tell my what's bad about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zone concept to handle this kind of actions. [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)

```
let LoadDetailsZone = Zone.current.fork({
  name: 'detailZone',
  onHasTask() {
    this.DataService.M4(this.SomeData1.Id, this.SomeData2.Id, this.SomeData3.Id).subscribe((Model4: Project.Models.Model4[]) => {
          this.SomeData4 = Model4;
      });
  }
})
LoadDetailsZone.run(() => {
  this.DataService.M1().subscribe((Model1: Project.Models.Model1[]) => {
      this.SomeData1 = Model1;
  });
  this.DataService.M2().subscribe((Model2: Project.Models.Model2[]) => {
      this.SomeData2 = Model2;
  });
  this.DataService.M3().subscribe((Model3: Project.Models.Model3[]) => {
      this.SomeData3 = Model3;
  });
})
```

You define a Zone with `onHasTask` function which is called after all the call in the zone.run().

Comment: Nice alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
this._villageService.GetAllVillages()
    .flatMap(
       (response) => {
         // take from the response what you want and use it for the next call
         this._villageService.GetAllWorkAreas(//pass the thing from your previous response here)
       }
    )
    .flatMap(
      ....
    )
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: This will not execute the request simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

You can use promises for that:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";

let p1 = this.DataService.M1().toPromise();
let p2 = this.DataService.M2().toPromise();
let p3 = this.DataService.M3().toPromise();

Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]).then(() => {
   this.DataService.M4();
});
```

Comment: Never use toPromise if it's not really needed. And you have a typo, it should be `toPromise()`

Comment: whats wrong in using toPromise() ?? I think this is a good solution

Comment: what kind of error? `import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";` to add support

Comment: @AmarnathRShenoy because you do not need to transform an Observable to a Promise to perform this. You can easily use `Observable.forkJoin()` to do the same.

Answer (score -2):

Just a game of Flags ;-)

```
public timer:any;
LoadDetails() {
    let dataCall1Completed = false;
    let dataCall2Completed = false;
    let dataCall3Completed = false;

    this.DataService.M1().subscribe((Model1 : Project.Models.Model1[]) => {
        this.SomeData1 = Model1;
        dataCall1Completed = true;
    });
    this.DataService.M2().subscribe((Model2 : Project.Models.Model2[]) => {
        this.SomeData2 = Model2;
        dataCall2Completed = true;
    });
    this.DataService.M3().subscribe((Model3 : Project.Models.Model3[]) => {
        this.SomeData3 = Model3;
        dataCall3Completed = true;
    });

    this.timer = setTimeout(dataCall4(), 1000)
}

dataCall4() {
    if (dataCall1Completed && dataCall2Completed && dataCall3Completed) {
        this.DataService.M4(this.SomeData1.Id, this.SomeData2.Id, this.SomeData3.Id).subscribe((Model4 : Project.Models.Model4[]) => {
            this.SomeData4 = Model4;
        });
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use setTimout() to perform stuff like this. You can simply use the Observable functionality to do this, no need for hacks.

Comment: Can we have nested observables

Comment: You can use `forkJoin`, unfortunately the RXJS 5.* documentation is really bad. The sourcecode is here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts ,but yeah, it's hard to understand.